# An ambiguous description in Dasgupta, 2019 regarding the coefficients and choosing baseline specification

Tags: applied-econometrics

Regarding the result table of [Dasgupta, 2019, table 3, p.2601](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300), where they examine the impact of anticollusion on asset growth

[image]

However, they describe that

> The dependent variable is the annual asset growth. In Column 1, we
> only consider the effect of a leniency law without any additional
> controls, and, in Column 2, we add firm-specific variables and several
> other variables to capture macroeconomic conditions and import
> competition. We see that leniency law passage is associated with
> higher asset growth. We choose the **latter specification to be our
> baseline**, and we find that the asset growth **increases by as much as 7%
> in our specification**, which corresponds to one-third of the
> unconditional mean in the sample.

I have two main questions here:

(1) I do not understand they say the asset growth **increases by as much as 7% in our specification**

(2) Why they choose the specification (2) as the baseline specification while it does not account for industry fixed effect or any industry covariate?

Comment: "as much as" means look at the max ... how many firms change industry? So if you already have firm fixed effects what is purpose of industry fixed effect?

Comment: thank you, @JesperHybel, a very clear suggestion, a small curiosity: In column (3). the author used the same independent variable set with column (2), but adding some more industry-level variables, can I ask what is it for?

Comment: Sorry don't know.